# Why does the Java compiler add an extra try-catch block?

Tags: java, byte-code

Suppose we compile this method using Java 6+ compiler:

```
void test(int x) {
    try {
        x += 777;
    } finally {
        x -= 333;
    }
}
```

The disassembled code would look like this:

```
test(I)V
    TRYCATCHBLOCK L0 L1 L2 null
    TRYCATCHBLOCK L2 L3 L2 null
   L0              // Start of try block
    IINC 1 777     // The body of try block
   L1              // Start of finally block in case of successful execution 
    IINC 1 -333    // Body of finally block
    GOTO L4        // End of 'success' finally block 
   L2              // Start of finally block in case of exception
    ASTORE 2       // Remember exception
   L3
    IINC 1 -333    // Duplicated body of finally block
    ALOAD 2        // Load remembered exception
    ATHROW         // Rethrow the exception 
   L4              // End of try/finally  
    RETURN
   L5
```

Obviously, this declaration specifies the "try" section and the beginning of the "finally" block:

```
    TRYCATCHBLOCK L0 L1 L2 null
```

But the next declaration looks strange:

```
    TRYCATCHBLOCK L2 L3 L2 null
```

Why does the Java compiler protect the exception while remembering it, and why does it specify itself as the handler recursively (i.e. the two `L2`s)?

Comment: Does the same happen if you use `catch` instead of finally?

Comment: @Devolus No. It adds single
    `TRYCATCHBLOCK L0 L1 L2 java/lang/Exception`

Comment: Same question on SO a few years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386917/strange-exception-table-entry-produced-by-suns-javac

Comment: I agree with Devolus.  I've never actually seen try{}finally{} in production code.

Comment: Daniel, not the same question.  The question "from a few years ago" explicitly states that his case occurs even with the presence of a catch block.

Comment: Ponomandr, which version of Java are you using?  Sun Java 1.6?  OpenJDK 1.6?  It makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

A guess. As we can can see there is no actual duplication of code, the multiple trycatch blocks function as goto labels under different cases of what failed or not (since a finally clause is also present). If you follow the program flow you can see that no duplication  takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I just disassembled this using java 8 compiler and the second trycatchblock is no longer being generated

```
test(I)V
   TRYCATCHBLOCK L0 L1 L2 null
  L0
   IINC 1 777
  L1
   IINC 1 -333
  L3
   GOTO L4
  L2
   FRAME SAME1 java/lang/Throwable
   ASTORE 2
   IINC 1 -333
   ALOAD 2
   ATHROW
  L4
   FRAME SAME
   RETURN
  L5
```

My guess is this is some legacy handling that is ignored by the JVM